# Pressing back button once stay on the same fragment, and if pressing twice, it will go back to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have following code

```
package com.example.covid19
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.add
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
import com.example.covid19.fragments.CountryListFragment
import com.example.covid19.fragments.CountryStatisticFragment
import com.example.covid19.fragments.onClickedListener


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), onClickedListener {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       //first time the app is launched
       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           setCountryFragment()
       }
   }

   private fun setCountryFragment() {
       supportFragmentManager.commit {
           setReorderingAllowed(true)
           add<CountryListFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
       }
   }

   private fun changeFragment(arg: String) {
       lateinit var nextFragment: Fragment
       val currentFragment: Fragment? =
           supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view)
       if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment is CountryListFragment) {
           nextFragment = CountryStatisticFragment.newInstance(arg)

       } else {
           nextFragment = CountryListFragment.newInstance()

       }
       supportFragmentManager.commit {
           setReorderingAllowed(true)
           replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, nextFragment)
           addToBackStack(null)
       }
   }
   override fun onItemClicked(arg: String) {
       changeFragment(arg)
   }
}
```

When i press button in the second fragment CountryStatisticFragment it blinks and stay on the same fragment. I have to press it twice to go to first fragment!
To "fix" it i had to add following code

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
        //this should not be needed, but pressing back one time, when being in CountryStatisticFragment leads to a transition to same fragment, CountryStatisticFragment
        super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

But it doesn't feel that it is the correct way to handle it. Anyone who has seen similar behaviour or can see what i am doing wong?

Comment: Why are you calling `addToBackStack(null)` in `setFragmentA()`? The first fragment you add should never be on the back stack

Comment: It didn't help! I have removed it now. The error is still there. The error occurs only when navigating back from FragmentB, Tested it on a separate "project" also,  with two simple fragments with only a a textview on each of the fragments works. However in my real project where both fragments have each a recycleview it doesn't work. The bug still appear. I suspect that it is a framework issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //first time the app is launched
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setFragmentA()
    }
}

private fun setFragmentA() {
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        setReorderingAllowed(true)
        add<FragmentA>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
        addToBackStack(null) // DELETE THIS     
}
```

First guess would be the call to `addToBackStack(null)` in `setFragmentA`. This adds the first fragment to the backstack so instead of just exiting when you press back, you pop the stack and end up in a weird state.

Comment: It didn't help! I have removed it now. The error is still there. The error occurs only when navigating back from FragmentB, Tested it on a separate "project" also,  with two simple fragments with only a a textview on each of the fragments works. However in my real project where both fragments have each a recycleview it doesn't work. The bug still appear. I suspect that it is a framework issue?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely this is "a framework issue" - you probably have a bug. Post more code that illustrates a complete working example of the Activity and Fragments. You've probably omitted something important from your original question.

Comment: See the code in the beginning of the thread now. It is the original code without any modifications! The main activity is responsible for interacting with fragments!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire and exact code for my activity.

```
package com.example.covid19


import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.add
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
import com.example.covid19.fragments.CountryListFragment
import com.example.covid19.fragments.CountryStatisticFragment
import com.example.covid19.fragments.onClickedListener


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), onClickedListener {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       //first time the app is launched
       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           setCountryFragment()
       }
   }

   private fun setCountryFragment() {
       supportFragmentManager.commit {
           setReorderingAllowed(true)
           add<CountryListFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)

       }
   }

   private fun changeFragment(arg: String) {
       lateinit var nextFragment: Fragment
       val currentFragment: Fragment? =
           supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view)
       if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment is CountryListFragment) {
           nextFragment = CountryStatisticFragment.newInstance(arg)

       } else {
           nextFragment = CountryListFragment.newInstance()


       }
       supportFragmentManager.commit {
           setReorderingAllowed(true)
           replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, nextFragment)
           addToBackStack(null)
       }
   }
   override fun onItemClicked(arg: String) {
       changeFragment(arg)
   }
}
```

CountryListFragment and CountryListFragment have both recyclerviews inside. This is just an hobby project i have done, and everything else works!

Comment: Don't "answer" your own question to add more info - delete this and edit your actual question so it's complete and accurate.

Comment: You asked for more code. I attached the complete code for activity where the interaction with fragment occurs! I will move the code to the beginning of the thread.